# Animation of line plots from multiple files

Tags: python, csv, memory, matplotlib

I am trying to add animation, or live graph features, to the plotting of these graphs. I have this code below which works very well for the plotting of multiple files but animation would be a good addition. At this point I am getting the max runtime warning about memory.

Here is part code I am running:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import animation as animation

```
def animationIRI():
    startList = [] # list of starting miles (float)
    iriRList = [] # list of IRI data (float)
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
    ax1.plot(startList, iriRList) # lists that I am graphing
    ax1.clear()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animationIRI(), interval=1000)
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

Here is the warning I am getting:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
 File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 424
max_open_warning, RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. 
Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`)   are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
```

Comment: You're calling `plt.figure()` every animation step, which explains why so many are being created. Could you clarify what you want it to do, specifically how many figures / subplots you want? (You may also want to take a look at [mcve] - can this example be simplified?)

Comment: Well that's what I thought too so I moved the fig1 to the top of the function but that still produced the same error. Yes ill simplify the code right now. My bad.

Comment: Well, `animationIRI` is the animation function so that will still create a new figure each interval. Right now I am confused about how the files relate to the animation.. But I await your edit :)

Comment: The files are appended to the lists which are being graphed and hopefully animated.